# All HTTP requests to local servers in waiting state for five seconds

Tags: networking, windows-10

I have a strange problem with my Windows 10 work laptop. Everything was fine before the holidays, but for the last few weeks I've had this bizzare problem.

Normal internet browsing is fine, but for all our local servers at work (all Nginx, mostly on CentOS 7 but one or two on Ubuntu) every single HTTP request is really slow. Looking in Firefox or Edge's inspector, they seem to sit in the 'Waiting' state for almost *exactly* five seconds before loading.

The issue is there whether I'm on wired Ethernet or via WiFi. It happens in Firefox, Edge, and even Curl (through Msys2).

It only seems to happen with HTTP - SSH to these servers is fine and I notice no unusual latency.

My colleagues don't have this issue at all, their requests are fast. I brought in my home laptop and the requests to these same servers are in the wait state for 20 to 200ms and everything feels fine. So it's only this one laptop.

I've tried everything I can think of, resetting the IP stack through netsh etc., making sure everything is up to date (drivers, browsers, Windows), disabling IPv6, and nothing changes it.

One interesting thing is that it only seems to happen when going to the server by hostname - most I don't have an option (because they serve multiple virtual hosts) but one only has a single virtual host so I can, and when I navigate to it via IP address it's fast but with the hostname it has the wait issue. But it's nothing to do with DNS resolution because I put the hostnames in my host file and it doesn't change things, and looking in the inspector DNS resolution is taking less than 1ms anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was actually the centrally managed antivirus software (Trend Micro OfficeScan) because its management server had stopped working. It must have been stopping connections to do some kind of real-time scan and then timing out after five seconds of not being able to contact the server.